# Section content won't resize while remaining within its container

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm creating a responsive, mobile first website and I am having a problem where **the content within the `#news` section won't stay within that section as the browser resizes.**

When this happened originally the content would expand and cover the footer area, so I searched and found someone saying I should put `overflow: auto` on the section but as you'll see in the screenshots this simply makes the content go behind the footer section which I also don't want.

**What I am wondering is how can I make it to where the news section will stay above the footer and resize as the browser expands.**

Here's a codepen that reproduces the issue using dummy images!! http://codepen.io/marlee/pen/OMeKWa

Let's start with screen shots:

[image]

[image]

What I'm showing here is when I expand the window the date and link disappear behind the footer section.

Here is the HTML for this section:

```
 <section id="news">
    <h2>Latest News</h2>
      <line></line>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <img src="images/tech.jpg" alt="New Product Strategy for SharePoint Flex in 2016" />
          <small>19 January 2016</small>
          <a href="#">LookOut Software accelerates innovation with SharePoint Flex, unveils product strategy for Spring and Summer 2016</a>
      </li>

      <li>
        <img src="images/world-economic-forum.png" alt="LookOut Software Chairman to participate in World Economic Forum in Toronto 2016" />
          <small>5 February 2016</small>
          <a href="#">LookOut Software Chairman to participate in the World Economic Forum Annual Meeting 2016</a>
      </li>

      <li>
        <img src="images/health.jpg" alt="LookOut Software joins the fight against the Zika virus" />
          <small>12 February 2016</small>
          <a href="#">LookOut Software announces partnership with the World Health Organization to combat Zika virus</a>
      </li>

      <li>
        <img src="images/render-logo.jpg" alt="LookOut founder to speak at Render Conference in Oxford" />
          <small>20 February 2016</small>
          <a href="#">LookOut Software founder and CEO to speak at Render Conference in Oxford, UK this April</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
 </section>

/* Footer */

<footer>
    <div class="footer-top">
      <div class="product-column">
        <h4>Products</h4>
          <ul class="products">
            <li>
              <a href="http://www.sharepointflex.com">SharePoint Flex</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Flex Platform</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Flex Enterprise</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Pricing</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="resources-column">
        <h4>Resources</h4>
          <ul class="resources">
            <li>
              <a href="#">Documentation</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Blog</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Get Started</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="about-column">
        <h4>About</h4>
          <ul class="about">
            <li>
              <a href="#">About Us</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Customers</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Partners</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="support-column">
        <h4>Support</h4>
          <ul class="support">
            <li>
              <a href="#">Help</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Contact</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Open a ticket</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer-bottom">
        <img src="images/lookout-temp.png">
        <p>&copy; 2016 LookOut Software</p>
    </div>
 </footer>
```

And the CSS:

```
/* Latest News Section */

#news{
height: 97rem;
background-color: white;
box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(6,8,8,0.15);
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
justify-content: flex-start;
align-items: center;
overflow: auto;
}

#news h2{
text-align: center;
}

line{
display: block;
width: 30%;
height: 1px;
background: #e8e8e8;
}

#news ul{
display: flex;
flex-flow: column;
list-style: none;
padding-left: 0;
}

#news li{
margin: 1em .5em;
}

#news img{
width: 100%;
}

#news a{
text-decoration: none;
color: #3a3a3a;
font-size: 1rem;
}

/* Footer CSS*/

/* Footer Top */

.footer-top{
background-color: #F0F0F0;
height: 24rem;
display: flex;
flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.footer-top ul{
list-style-type: none;
padding-left: 1.5rem;
}

.footer-top h4{
padding-left: 1.5rem;
margin-bottom: .5rem;
}

.footer-top a{
text-decoration: none;
color: #3a3a3a;
font-size: 1rem;
}

.resources-column, .about-column, .product-column{
padding: .5rem;
}

.support-column{
padding-left: 2.3rem;
}

/* Footer Bottom */

.footer-bottom{
background-color: #F6F6F6;
height: 10rem;
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
}

.footer-bottom img{
height: 6.25rem;
width: 15.625rem;
}

.footer-bottom p{
font-size: .80rem;
}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Can you add the full image URLs, so we can reproduce the problem? Thanks.

Comment: Hi @Michael_B I am not sure what exactly "full image URL" means.

Comment: I've added dummy images to your code, and everything scales just fine: https://jsfiddle.net/p714vcw3/

Comment: Ah, okay I see. I'm going to edit the question and add the footer html and css so you can reproduce the whole problem. Thanks for your help. @Michael_B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've limited the height of the `#news` section with `height: 97rem;`.

This fixed height prevents the layout from adjusting to different screen sizes.

Instead of this:

```
#news { height: 97rem; }
```

Try this:

```
#new { min-height: 97rem; }
```

And you don't need the `overflow: auto` anymore.

Comment: Hmmm, I still seem to be having the same issue. However I just realized that the content going behind the footer can be scrolled. I can scroll to the bottom of the news section when it expands. I'm guessing this is because of the overflow: auto?? @michael

Comment: Yes, 'overflow: auto`, in most browsers, will launch a scrollbar when the content overflows.

Comment: I see. Thank you. Is it apparent from my code what exactly is keeping the content of the news section from staying within the section? Is it just because the images continue to grow in size as the browser expands, causing the content to push below the footer?

Comment: If you can reproduce the problem in a demo (e.g., jsfiddle.net), I / we can help you more effectively. Post a demo here or in your question that illustrates the problem and contains all relevant code.

Comment: Got it. I will do it in codepen as I'm more familiar with the interface. @michael

Comment: Okay, I have recreated the problem in this codepen using dummy images of the same size. Since I have only designed thus far for a mobile screen you'll have to shrink your browser down, and then expand it to see the problem with the #news section going behind the footer. [link]( http://codepen.io/marlee/pen/OMeKWa)

@michael